# VS Code setting absolute paths for modern browser js imports incorrectly

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, import, browser, absolute-path

Working on native browser app using pure javascript, that is native to the chrome engine, with raw js files being served to chrome from a subdirectory in my project. When using visual studio code I would like it it always use absolute paths when autocompleting imports like this:

I type:

```js
import { createWorkletProcessor }
```

And Want VS Code to autocomplete with this with the correct type bindings

```js
import { createWorkletProcessor } from "/common/create-worklet-processor.js";
```

With my current settings, VS Code gives me this:

```
import { createWorkletProcessor } from "common/create-worklet-processor.js";
```

And does not give me the forward slash I need in the path. This results in the following error in Chrome (or any browser based on web standards for path resolution):

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "common/create-worklet-processor.js". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

When I manually add a forward slash, it fixes the problem with the browser, but I lose all the autocomplete type bindings in VSCode.

How do I fix this in VS Code to have autocomplete work correctly for my browser import resolution on absolute js paths, as well as keep my type bindings?

I added a jsconfig.json file like this

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "baseUrl": "./app/",
  }
}
```

I also set my default settings for import path auto complete in my settings.json file for VS Code:

```json
{

    "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative",
    "javascript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js"
}
```

I thought this would resolve the issue for setting up imports for browser development.

Comment: I also having the same problem. Did you find a solution?